# supporting for each loop in classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

how can i add "for each" support for my class in c++0x and visual studio 2010?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use STL containers instead of rolling your own? (Besides the misinformed bias against the STL)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way would be to add iterator support, with `begin()` and `end()` functions. The ranged-based for-loop uses them, and this also gives your class the richer set of functionality iterators provide.

Comment: iterators is too slow (in game developing) and i don't want to use stl

Comment: @user: I do game programming, and you're horribly mistaken. Program in assembly if you're that concerned, or learn to actually program C++. I'm actually surprised people still hold such ridiculous positions, I thought that C-to-C++ wave died out long ago. Program good solid C++, don't under-estimate your compiler, profile instead of guess, and move on. Use the standard library, it's there for a reason; I can't imagine how nasty your code must look without it.

Answer (score -2):

You must make the class support the IEnumerable Interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx